# Failed to start open network operating system using command systemctl

Tags: systemctl

i follow the admin guide to install onos and when i issue the following command:

sudo systemctl status onos.service

it output a error message that show failed to start open network operating system. However it seems like it failed to start due to the missing karaf (from the command `tail /var/log/syslog` line 2 and 3)?

thus I tried to create a symbolic link named karaf that points to the existing `apache-karaf-3.0.8 directory` under /opt/onos, the exact same error message still exists

I am using ubuntu 18 LTE Desktop version, if that helps

anybody able to help me with that

the following is what under my `opt/onos` directory:

```
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt/onos$ ls -l
total 28
drwxrwxrwx   9 sdn root  4096 Dec 19 17:04 apache-karaf-3.0.8
drwxr-xr-x 174 sdn root 12288 Dec 19 16:59 apps
drwxrwxrwx   2 sdn root  4096 Nov 29 15:40 bin
drwxrwxrwx   2 sdn root  4096 Nov 29 15:40 init
lrwxrwxrwx   1 sdn root    21 Dec 23 20:19 karaf -> ./apache-karaf-3.0.8/
-rwxrwxrwx   1 sdn root     6 Nov 29 15:40 VERSION
```

i have attached a sequence of failed message from different commands

when use the command `sudo systemctl status onos.service`, it gives the following

```
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~$ sudo systemctl status onos.service
● onos.service - Open Network Operating System
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/onos.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Sun 2018-12-23 17:37:43 EST; 4s ago
  Process: 3586 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/onos stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3569 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/onos start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Stopped Open Network Operating System.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start Open Network Operating System.
```

when use the command `tail /var/log/syslog` to get some more detail information, i get the following

```
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~$ tail /var/log/syslog
Dec 23 17:37:42 maxyou-virtual-machine onos[3586]: sudo: /opt/onos/karaf/bin/status: command not found
Dec 23 17:37:42 maxyou-virtual-machine onos[3586]: ONOS/karaf is not running
Dec 23 17:37:42 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Started Open Network Operating System.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Stopped Open Network Operating System.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: onos.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Dec 23 17:37:43 maxyou-virtual-machine systemd[1]: Failed to start Open Network Operating System.
Dec 23 17:37:54 maxyou-virtual-machine gnome-shell[2120]: pushModal: invocation of begin_modal failed
```

from line 2 and 3 of above's output, i check check if the **status** exists

```
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~$ ls
bin  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  examples.desktop  Music  opt  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~$ cd opt
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt$ ls
onos  onos-1.15.0.tar.gz
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt$ cd onos
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt/onos$ ls
apache-karaf-3.0.8  apps  bin  init  karaf  options  VERSION
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt/onos$ cd karaf/bin
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~/opt/onos/karaf/bin$ ls
client  client.bat  instance  instance.bat  karaf  karaf.bat  setenv  setenv.bat  shell  shell.bat  start  start.bat  status  status.bat  stop  stop.bat
```

but when i try to run the command `sudo: /opt/onos/karaf/bin/status` manually it gives the following:

```
maxyou@maxyou-virtual-machine:~$ sudo ./opt/onos/karaf/bin/status
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
Not Running ...
```

i have tried my best to show the error message from different perspective

can somebody tell me why `sudo systemctl status onos.service` gives error message and how to fix it?

thanks

Comment: It's not complaining about a missing directory, but about a missing binary (`/opt/onos/karaf/bin/status`). Just blindly renaming a directory won't help you with this. Also, *don't* show us error messages and log entries as screenshots, that's nearly useless. Use copy/paste and the formatting tools.

Comment: @Sven, i have fixed my post, can you give me more pointers of why that happens